# istream_iterator( istream_type& stream ) points to different value if initialize twice

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(int args, char *argv[])
{
    vector<int> vec = { 123, 456, 789 };
    auto i1 = vec.begin();  //123
    auto i2 = vec.begin();  //123
    cout << *i1 << endl << *i2 << endl;
    istringstream istr("123 456 789");
    istream_iterator<int> i3(istr);  //123
    istream_iterator<int> i4(istr);  //456
    cout << *i3 << endl << *i4 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result of `i4` is out of my expectation( I mean I was thinking that it for sure should act like an ordinary container iterator). How does this work? I only got this from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator)

> 2) Initializes the iterator, stores the address of stream in a data member, and performs the first read from the input stream to initialize the cached value data member.

Comment: `performs the first read from the input stream` - this side-effects `istr`, advancing it.